# Table Tag Inside Anchor Tag

Tags: html

Can there be a table inside a tag?For example:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" style="display:block">  
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>    
</a>
```

I tried the previous code. It's working fine in Google Chrome, but it's not working in Firefox.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [draft specification allows it](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) so long as you could put a table where you put the anchor (it has a [transparent content model](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#transparent))…

```
<div><a …><table>…</table></a></div>   <!-- Allowed -->
<span><a …><table>…</table></a></span> <!-- Not allowed -->
```

…but HTML 4 does not (so you may have browser support problems).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's valid HTML5 but invalid HTML 4.01. The following snippet [passes HTML5 validation](http://validator.w3.org/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#">
        <table></table>
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

As far as whether you should do it, that's another question. You probably shouldn't.

Comment: @saorabh, no I haven't. As I said this is valid HTML5 (which is still a draft) and not something I would recommend you using.

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you just add an onclick to `<table>`?

```
<table onclick="window.location='page.html'">
    <tbody valign="top">
        <tr>
            <td>content</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Depends on JavaScript. Not accessible without a pointing device.

Comment: Actually i am writing for e-mailers where mailer server negalates javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You may use a `<BUTTON>` tag and embed the table inside it. To remove button borders set:

```
style='border:none; margin:0; padding:0; outline:none;
```

For example:

```
<BUTTON type="button" onclick="" style="border:none; margin:0; padding:0;"><table>...</table></BUTTON>
```